# Understanding database/sql

Tags: postgresql, go

I am playing around with the `database/sql` package trying to see how it works and understand what would happen if you don't call `rows.Close()` etc.

So I wrote the following piece of code for inserting a model to database:

```
func (db Database) Insert(m model.Model) (int32, error) {
    var id int32

    quotedTableName := m.TableName(true)

    // Get insert query
    q, values := model.InsertQuery(m)

    rows, err := db.Conn.Query(q, values...)
    if err != nil {
        return id, err
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&id)

        if err != nil {
            return id, err
        }

    }

    return id, nil
}
```

I don't call `rows.Close()` on purpose to see the consequences. When setting up the database connection I set some properties such as:

```
conn.SetMaxOpenConns(50)
conn.SetMaxIdleConns(2)
conn.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Second*60)
```

Then I attempt to insert 10000 records:

```
for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    lander := models.Lander{
        // ...struct fields with random data on each iteration
    }

    go func() {
        Insert(&lander)
    }()
}
```

(It lacks error checking, context timeouts etc. but for the purpose of playing around it gets the job done). When I execute piece of code from above I expect to see at least some errors regarding database connections however the data gets inserted without problems (all 10000 records). When I check the `Stats()` I see the following:

`{MaxOpenConnections:50 OpenConnections:1 InUse:0 Idle:1 WaitCount:9951 WaitDuration:3h9m33.896466243s MaxIdleClosed:48 MaxLifetimeClosed:2}`

Since I didn't call `rows.Close()` I expected to see more OpenConnections or more InUse connections because I am never releasing the connection (maybe I might be wrong, but this is the purpose of `Close()` to release a Connection and return it to the pool).

So my question is simply what do these `Stats()` mean and why are there no errors whatsoever when doing the insertion. Also why aren't there more OpenConnections or InUse ones and what are the real consequences of not calling `Close()`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for `Rows`:

> If Next is called and returns false and there are no further result sets, the Rows are closed automatically and it will suffice to check the result of Err.

Since you iterate all the results, the result set is closed.

Comment: I followed the examples from https://golang.org/src/database/sql/example_test.go and when they iterate using `Next()` they still do a `defer rows.Close()`

Comment: Read the docs for `Rows`. If you iterate all the results, there is no need to close the result set. Also, `Close` is idempotent, so it is good practice to defer close in case you don't end up iterating the whole resultset.